# Trying to understand how to pass variables to a CustomValidation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to understand how to pass data to my custom validation that I created.

I have this model.

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter a Start Date")]  
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter an End Date")]
    [CustomValidation(typeof(DateCompareValidation), "ValidateDates")]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

This is my validator.

```
public class DateCompareValidation
{
    public static ValidationResult ValidateDates(object value, ValidationContext context)
    {
        return new ValidationResult("You are wrong");
    }
}
```

The first time I had public static ValidationResult ValidateDates() and it errored out for

```
"..must match the expected signature: public static ValidationResult ValidateDates(object value, ValidationContext context)."
```

so I added the necessary parameters.

Now debugging the class I see the variable "value" has my end date.

I don't quite understand how it knows what parameters it needed.

In addition I would like to know how can I pass the start date or the MyModel class so that I can work on my validation logic?

Comment: What do you want you attribute to do? Compare that `DateTime` is greater than `StartDate`?

Comment: Yes. In this particular case all I want is to make sure I have a valid date rage entered.  Once I understand how this all works I may have a need to write more complex validators.

Comment: I suggest your read [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about just adding the logic to the class and implement the IValidateObject?

```
   public class MyClass : IValidatableObject
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter a Start Date")]  
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter an End Date")]
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext context)
        {
            if (EndDate < StartDate)
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("Invalid date range: End date must be greater then the Start Date");
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although it does not preciselly answer your question, I would recommend you to take a look at [FluentValidation](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation).
It can completelly replace built in ASP.NET MVC attribute-based validation with fluent-syntax interface (using user-defined validator classes).

For example, if you wanted to validate that `StartDate` preceeds `EndDate`, it may look like:

```
// validator class for your view model
public class MyModelValidator : AbstractValidator<MyModel>
{
    public MyModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(m => m.EndDate).NotNull().WithMessage("Please enter an End Date");
        RuleFor(m => m.StartDate).NotNull().WithMessage("Please enter a Start Date")
            .LessThan(m => m.EndDate).WithMessage("Start Date must preceed End Date");
    }
}

// declare MyModelValidator as a validator for view model
[Validator(typeof(MyModelValidator))]
public class MyModel
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

If you're interested to try it out, be sure to get the `FluentValidation.MVC5` (or appropriate for the version of MVC you're using, at the time of writing this post `FluentValidation.MVC6` is in Beta) nuget. All you'd have to then is to register it in global.asax like so:

```
 protected void Application_Start()
 {
     ...
     FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

this may help you.

```
class CustomLengthValidatorAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="CustomLengthValidatorAttribute" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="maxLength">The maximum length.</param>
    public CustomLengthValidatorAttribute(int maxLength)
    {
        this.MaxLength = maxLength;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the minimum length.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The minimum length.
    /// </value>
    public int MaxLength { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Validates the specified value with respect to the current validation attribute.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The value to validate.</param>
    /// <param name="validationContext">The context information about the validation operation.</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// An instance of the <see cref="T:System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult" /> class.
    /// </returns>
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        string fieldName = validationContext.MemberName;
        if (Convert.ToString(value).Trim().Length > this.MaxLength)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage = fieldName + " should not be longer than " + this.MaxLength + " character");
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```